# How to customise editor's background color in the ruby plugin for eclipse?

Tags: ruby, colors, background, aptana, customization

How to customize editor's background color in the aptana's ruby plug-in 3.0.3.201108101424-7e-7Q7f4b2QfPuHR for eclipse? (Descriptions for older versions do not apply to this version and settings in Preferences | General | Text Editors do not have any effect.)

Answer (score 4):

You could customize the theme settings in Preferences > Aptana > Themes, e.g. changing the theme used in the combo box to "Eclipse" would switch the editor background to white.

You could also read more on http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Themes.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer!

You don't go to Preferences/Appearance to change the background color but to Preferences/Aptana Studio/Themes

There you can change the background color from black to white!