# Editor background color for HTML cannot be changed in Aptana Studio 3.0

Tags: colors, background, aptana, aptana3

I'm running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.4.201108101506 in standalone mode.  I have repeatedly tried to change the background color of the default HTML editor (looks like it might actually be the PHP editor).

I've tried to change preferences for every available editor, but it still remains black.

I did notice a small "sliver" of a window to the left of the main window that was changing it's colors as I changed preferences.  I have no idea, therefore, which window I'm editing in.

I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious and I should have read about it in the Manual (which I did read for every reference to background).

The JavaScript editor behaves properly (e.g., background changes when I ask it to).

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324455/how-to-customise-editors-background-color-in-the-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse).